# Access member variables from the MainClass inside a class defined in MainClass?

Tags: c#, class, oop

I want to access the member variables inside a class MainClass, from inside a class defined in that MainClass. Can i do that?

```
public class MainClass
{
    public int x = 1;

    public class Class1
    {
        public void class1Function()
        {
            this.x = 4; //somehow access the x of instance of MainClass
        }
    }

    public static class Class2
    {
        public static void class2Function()
        {
            this.x = 5; //also can i do this from a static function?
        }

    }

    public void mainFunction()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(this.x); //this works just fine, obviously
    }
}
```

Comment: `Class1` doesn't have any `x` member, much less one that is `static`. Perhaps you want to pass a reference to the owning object to the nested class? See also the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class1` and `Class2` cannot access `x` from `MainClass` because *an instance of a nested class isn't associated with an instance of the outer class.* (Corrected based on Joe Sewell's hint)

You could inherit `MainClass` like this: `public class Class1 : MainClass`. Then you can access `this.x`.

Accessing a mutable variable from a static context, which is the case for Class2 is not possible. If you want to use `x` in `class2Function` you could pass it and return the modified version that you need (Closure of Operations).